# How to add calendar in a "form_for"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in Rails, currently, I am working on my form (using '`form_for`'), for some reason, I have to use `form_for`, can not use *sematic_form_for*, please don't ask me to use that.

My question is if I stick to use **form_for**, is there any way to implement a calendar selection field for date selection. (I know there is 'select_date' and 'date_select' helper, but they are drop down menus)

```
=form_for :myobject do |form|
  =form.??? /how to add a calender selection here??
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend using `date_select` so that users who do not or cannot effectively use JavaScript can still interact with your form.

That said, for those users who do have JavaScript enabled, the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) is very slick and can integrate with Rails.

[This blog post](http://blog.brzezinka.eu/webmaster-tips/ruby/ruby-on-rails-formtastic-jquery-ui-datepicker) contains some details about integrating with Rails, and though it uses **formtastic**, it can be adapted.